# What does "on which" mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I am VERY confused by the usage and meaning of "**on which** " in this sentence. Could anyone help me with it please? Many thanks!

The context is that Elizabeth and the Gardiners were talking about the elopement of Lydia and Wickham.

Here is the sentence:

> “When they all removed to Brighton, therefore, you had no reason, I
>   suppose, to believe them fond of each other?”
>
> “Not the slightest. I can remember no symptom of affection on either
>   side, and had anything of the kind been perceptible, **you must be aware
>   that ours is not a family on which it could be thrown away**. When
>   first he entered the corps, she was ready enough to admire him, but so
>   we all were. Every girl in or near Meryton was out of her senses about
>   him for the first two months. But he never distinguished her by any
>   particular attention, and, consequently, after a moderate period of
>   extravagant and wild admiration, her fancy for him gave way, and
>   others of the regiment, who treated her with more distinction, again
>   became her favourites.”
>
> *from Pride and Prejudice, by Jane Austen*

Comment: I am sure that "on which" refers to "our family". To rearrange it, "no symptom of affection that was perceptible could be thrown away on our family". What I don't understand is the meaning of "thrown away", or of the whole sentence.

Comment: my guess is that "our family" is eager to marry their five daughters; so they would not "miss" any symptom of them falling in love. What I really don't get is that why "on" used here?

Comment: 'Thrown away on' in the sense of 'wasted on', I suppose. (That is, given to them to no purpose.)

Comment: @user86301 and Kate Bunting, Given the context of eagerness to marry them off, and "wasted on", that makes sense.